# Blogs link from the not existing community page refers to 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, 404-not-found

The “blogs” link from the [not existing community page](https://404.stackexchange.com/), e.g:

> [image: not existing community]

refers to another not existing page:

> [image: blogs are dead]

Looks like blogs link should refer to the same page as for “blog” link in the footer:

> [image: footer blog]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed the blogs link since there's one leading to the company blog in the footer on that page as well.