# Site not found page with broken links

Tags: bug, status-completed, broken-link, 404-not-found

When I try to access the page http://elections.stackexchange.com, it redirects to **Site not found** page. There I can see two broken links.

- In the right hand side top, **Blogs** points to https://stackexchange.com/blogs and it redirects to Page not found page. I hope the URL should be link to https://stackoverflow.blog/

> [image: Blogs]

- In the footer **Legal** points to http://elections.stackexchange.com/@Urls.Legal.Home, that is the invalid URL. I hope the URL should be link to https://stackoverflow.com/legal

> [image: Legal]

Comment: Highly related: _"[elections.stackexchange.com isn't loading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294719/elections-stackexchange-com-isnt-loading)"_. From 16 months ago...

Comment: I reported about [blog link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310258/339911) 3 months ago, but didn’t notice for legal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed now - the Blogs link is gone, and I fixed the text replacement for the URL to Legal.